# Alter form button title

Tags: 7, forms

I use this to alter field labels:

```
function ninesixty_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['name']['#title'] = t('Name');
}
```

But how do I change the title of the button? The button is `<button>` not `<input>` and it's for node creation form. Form id is `titles-node-form`.

[image]

Comment: Do You want to change value "Save" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

In place of name put button name.

```
$form['name']['#value'] = t('Name');
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Hmm not working.

Comment: Optimus, TBI Infotech should be correct. Here is a link to the form [submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) button code.